# Why do I get this error "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()).]General network error" with ASP pages

Tags: sql-server, networking, asp-classic

Occasionally, on a ASP (classic) site users will get this error:

```
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionRead (recv()).]General network error.
```

Seems to be random and not connected to any particular page.  The SQL server is separated from the web server and my guess is that every once and a while the "link" goes down between the two. Router/switch issue... or has someone else ran into this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same setup as yours (ie separate web and database server), I've seen it from time to time and it has always been a connection problem between the servers - typically when the database server is being rebooted but sometimes when there's a comms problem somewhere in the system. I've not seen it triggered by any problems with the ASP code itself, which is why you're seeing it apparently at random and not connected to a particular page.

Answer (score 0):

I'd seen this error many times. It could be caused by many things including network errors too :).

But one of the reason could be built-in feature of MS-SQL.

The feature detects DoS attacks -- in this case too many request from web server :).

But I have no idea how we fixed it :(.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server configuration Manager

Disable TCP/IP , Enable Shared Memory & Named Pipes

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution exactly and not the same environment. However I get this error in a VBA/Excel program, and the problem is I have a hanging transaction which has not been submitted in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). After closing SSMS, everything works. So the lesson is a hanging transaction can block sprocs from proceeding (obvious fact, I know!). Hope this help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

open command prompt - Run as administrator and type following command on the client side

```
netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off
```

Comment: Could you explain your answer?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I had this error from Excel, which would hang on an EXEC which worked fine within SSMS. I've seen queries with problems before, which were also OK within SSMS, due to 'parameter sniffing' and unsuitable cached query plans. Making a minor edit to the SP cured the problem, and it worked OK afterwards in its orginal form. I'd be interested to hear if anyone has encountered this scenario too. Try the good old `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)` :)